# Getting a weird HTTP ERROR 500 on running query on a specific database table

Tags: sql-server-2014, laravel-5.4

I have tried doing this

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM policies";
$policies = DB::select($query);
```

And also this
    `$policies = Policy::all();`
Whenever I try to do this, this happens[image]

here is my controller function

```
public function getPremiumCollectionReport (Request $request) {
    $policies = Policy::all();
    echo $policies;
}
```

Other queries run perfectly well for other models and tables. And if I run the raw query in the sql server, it runs perfectly as well.
Can anyone help me find a solution? I don't have a clue.

Comment: You can put exception handling in the code and check what is the error by debugging the code..

Answer (score 1):

I just found out that there were too many policies in that table for the server to handle. If I run the query for a smaller number of policies, the query runs successfully. It only happens when I try to select a large number of policies.